# Ubuntu does not boot after install

Tags: installation, boot, wubi, windows-xp

I have installed Ubuntu form a CD on my laptop and on my desktop PC (both with Windows XP).

After installation I can choose what system should be booted, Windows XP or Ubuntu, on my laptop and it works fine, but on the desktop after rebooting, Windows XP starts and I have no way to boot Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu "As a program" within Windows? (Using Wubi).

Answer (score 2):

EasyBCD does not work with XP - needs Vista or 7.

Best solution for starters is *boot-repair*. When you run *boot-repair* be sure to update it before running it - it gives you that option.

If the one click option does not work, you can try the *Purge and reinstall* option.

Answer (score 0):

Please run msconfig.exe and find option responsible for displaying other systems. Set time for lets say 30 seconds.

Comment: ok i will try it after work, and post info.

Answer (score 0):

Run GParted from the live-CD on your desktop machine and verify that the installer has set up the root and swap partitions for Ubuntu.  If these are present, it probably means that, for some reason, the installer failed to reset the Windows master boot record (MBR) so that the GRUB dual-boot menu isn't being initiated.  If this is the problem, try using Boot-Repair to rectify the situation.  Complete instructions on how to download, install and use Boot-Repair are available at:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  If this doesn't work, just try re-installing Ubuntu on the desktop.  It's quite likely that you have experienced just a transient glitch.

Comment: Boot-Repair solved the problem. Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

Download [EasyBCD](http://download.cnet.com/EasyBCD/3000-2094_4-10556865.html) and add Ubuntu to the Windows Boot Loader.It's fairly easy to do so with EasyBCD. You should be able to boot to Ubuntu on startup then.

Comment: The asker is using Windows XP, so this will not work.